# How to override a class to not use a CSS property?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

Suppose I have the file `_buttons.scss` :

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: $btn-font-family;
  font-weight: $btn-font-weight;
  color: $body-color;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: if($link-decoration == none, null, none);
  white-space: $btn-white-space;
}
```

And now in my override file 'buttons.scss', I want to remove the `color` and add my custom font family and weight:

```
.btn {
      font-family: $custom-font-family;
      font-weight: $custom-font-weight;
}
```

Now, If I want to use the `.btn` class on an `<a>`, it will still take the color of the `.btn` class from Bootstrap because of the generated CSS file instead of the `<a>` defined color.

For example in the html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Attachment <span class="badge" data-bind="text: Documents().length">1</span></a>
```

How can I prevent that?

**EDIT** :
The compiled css will be something like:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI Light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

So, It will still use the `#212529` color for the `.btn` class that is coming from bootstrap.

Comment: hard to say without seeing the html code but try to use `color: inherit; ` or `color: inherit !important;`

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I have edited the questions to add an example of the html code.

Comment: Are you loading your override file _after_ the core file? This should just work.

Comment: @isherwood, Yes it is loaded after the original bootstrap file.  I have edited my question to add how the compiled css would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set manually the color to "unset"

```
.btn {
  font-family: $custom-font-family;
  font-weight: $custom-font-weight;
  color: unset; /* or "inherit" or whatever, based on your needs */
}
```

this is the correct way to override the CSS property, be careful that you might need the !important following the CSS rules based on your CSS frameworks needs. In other words, if you can't work on load order, you need to specify the !important (don't if you can) :)

if you don't specify the color as you are doing right now, you are just overriding the other properties and keeping the color

Answer (score 1):

set color manually the color "unset"

```
.btn {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI Light", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: unset
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding `!important` to your CSS property should help.

[About !import on w3schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp)

```
.btn {
  font-family: $custom-font-family !important;
  font-weight: $custom-font-weight !important;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. Load order should be sufficient, and `!important` makes further customization more difficult. Note that you misspelled the first instance.